# android custom font not showing

Tags: android, fonts

i have a problem where nothing shows up when i assign a custom font to a view.

```
TextView statsView1, statsView2, statsView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);



    statsView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.statsView);
    statsView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats1);
    statsView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats2);
    Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Pretendo.ttf");
    statsView.setTypeface(font);
    statsView2.setTypeface(font);
    InitialSetupUI();
    Calculate();
}
```

So i first assign the text views and font in the on create method.

```
public void Calculate() {

    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            TotalStats stats1 = new TotalStats(player, car, wheel, glide);
            TotalStats stats2 = new TotalStats(player2, car2, wheel2,
                    glide2);
            statsView1.setText(String.valueOf(stats1.speed) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.speedWater) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.speedAir) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.speedGround) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.accel) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.weight) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.hand) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.handWater) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.handAir) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.handGround) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.trac) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats1.mt) + "\n");
            statsView2.setText(String.valueOf(stats2.speed) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.speedWater) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.speedAir) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.speedGround) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.accel) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.weight) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.hand) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.handWater) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.handAir) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.handGround) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.trac) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(stats2.mt) + "\n");

        }

    });

}
```

Ignore all the new lines.. 
I then try to output the text to the view but nothing shows up. Its worth noting that the statView textview contains only text in the xml and it does show up.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statsView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Speed\nWater Speed\nAir Speed\nGround Speed\nAcceleration\nWeight\nHandling\nWater Handling\nAir Handling\nGround Handling\nTraction\nMini Turbo"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

I think the problem is commucating the textviews between the functions? Any help is appreciated.

Update:
I changed the statView2 setText value to

```
    statsView2.setText("test");
```

and it successfully printed out "test" in the font. So that means the problem is in these lines

```
statsView1.setText(String.valueOf(stats1.speed) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.speedWater) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.speedAir) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.speedGround) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.accel) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.weight) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.hand) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.handWater) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.handAir) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.handGround) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.trac) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(stats1.mt) + "\n");
```

But i dont know what could be affecting it to not output because it outputs with the default font.

Comment: I used a different font and now its working

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change getAssets() to getContext().getAssets() in order to get the .ttf file in the following line:-
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Pretendo.ttf");

Comment: See but the statView text view loads with the proper font so i know its not a loading error. Its just statView1 and statView2 in the calculate function that aren't showing.